# Help to understand 'fresh' in "nonstop inspiration delivered fresh to your feed"

Tags: word-usage

> Follow us on Instagram, Facebook, and Twitter for nonstop inspiration delivered **fresh** to your feed, every day.

I can probably get what the sentence is trying to convey. But I have some difficulty to understand the usage of **fresh** here. Does it work as adjective or adverb? Is *'inspiration' 'fresh'*? Or *deliver fresh stuff to your feed*?
I am a bit confused.

The [full source](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/male-salon-owner-punches-black-mother-face-child-shoplifts-keychain-221119278.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**delivered fresh** is normally used of consumables that can perish or go stale. It is a marketing slogan.  They will be delivered in a state of freshness. *...[delivered fresh to your door](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22delivered%20fresh%20to%20your%20door%22&oq=%22delivered%20fresh%20to%20your%20door%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.8087j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)*. Since inspiration cannot go stale or perish, the use is figurative, and in the final analysis more or less nonsensical, and so the tone is ad-lingo jaunty, a kind of self-conscious "meta" witticism.

**inspiration** is the object of the preposition **for** (**follow us ... *for* inspiration**).

**delivered fresh** is a participle clause which modifies **inspiration**: inspiration (which is) delivered fresh.

**delivered fresh** is a passive construction.  The object of the delivery, **( (which (inspiration))**,  is the implicit subject of the clause by virtue of the relative relationship of the clause to the noun it modifies.

**fresh** therefore is an object complement or a subject complement, depending on how you analyze it. In any case, **fresh** is the state of the inspiration upon  delivery.

A word that expresses the state of a thing is adjectival.

Comment: I would interpret “fresh” in the case of inspiration to be “new” as in “fresh faces” and not necessarily the opposite of “stale”.  I think they actually meant “fresh inspiration delivered” but as often happens in sloppy marketing writing, they got tripped up by a common combination of words (delivered fresh).

Comment: @ColleenV: I think your interpretation would have a firmer foundation if they'd written "fresh inspiration delivered to your feed"  instead of  **delivered fresh to your feed**.  That **feed** is a second-cousin of **food**  reinforces the perish/stale implications of the marketing slogan.

Comment: Can we also comprehend 'fresh' here as an adverb to modify 'delivered'?

Comment: @dan: No. The delivery itself is not "fresh", as in *These roses were freshly delivered, and yet they're drooping*, that is, delivered very recently. Rather, what is delivered is fresh.

Comment: A side question: you wrote: "delivered fresh is normally used of consumables". I'm curious if 'used of' is the same as 'used for'? I don't see 'used of' is a set in dictionaries.

Comment: @dan: **used of** and **used for** are more-or-less synonymous. In lexicographical contexts, **used of** is used far more often than **used for**.  That you cannot find the combination in dictionaries which show collocations doesn't mean the collocation is invalid.  You will see it being used by lexicographers themselves among the results of this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22used%20of%20things%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @dan: When we say **X is used of Y** we mean that X is employed in predicates about Y.  *predicated of Y*.  When we say **X is used for Y** it is not quite the same; it means that X is used *to express* Y.  But that distinction is not observed by all speakers.

Answer (score 6):

You can understand it as either an adjective or an adverb, really.

From [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/fresh):

> *adj*.
>
> 1.a. New to one's experience; not encountered before: *fresh evidence*.
>
> *adv.*
>
> Recently; newly: *fresh out of milk; muffins baked fresh daily*.

The meaning is essentially the same regardless: you receive new "inspiration" as it is generated. The inspiration is new and so it is "fresh," and because its the first time you are seeing it, it is being delivered "fresh" to you.